# OutOfMemoryError when passing large String

Tags: java, gwt

My web app experience OutOfMemory error when passing around base64 String on the client side that it manage to get from the the clipboard image.

The poblem happen when the large String is passed as argument to other method.

What is a work around in passing around large base64 String with GWT

Comment: Maybe you're simply out of memory. How much memory have you given your the JVM running your web server (and which server are you using) ?. Or perhaps you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Try parse using [Base64InputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html).

Comment: Java should only pass around a reference to the object, thus there should only be one instance of it and a few 4 or 8 byte references. The cause of running out of memory must be somewhere else, or you've phrased what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: _Memory usage:_ Should you be using JSF, keeping the state on the client side, and setting the limits lower, would help.

Comment: Which server are you using?? tomcat??

Comment: Are you using GWT development mode? Sometimes when you deploy your application using eclipse's jetty gwt plugin + development mode it throws an OutOfMemoryError if you have default JVM memory settings.

Comment: Sorry I'm using my phone.  The question was half baked due to typing difficulty

Comment: Yes in development mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem happen when the large String is passed as argument to other method.

No it isn't!

Passing a String as an argument *will not* cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.

The OOME that you are seeing is either being caused by creating the `String` object, or by doing something to the `String` object that causes new objects to be created.  It is not being caused by passing the String, no matter how large it is.

---

If you need suggestions on how to deal with it, you will need to show us the code that is creating the String and the code that is using it.  But the general approach to dealing with overly-large chunks of data, is process the data in a way that avoids representing it all in memory at the same time.

Comment: -1 String is wired in Java, its more than a primitive, its less than an Object. Its parameterization is like an "value" (that needs extra-memory) but its initialized like an "reference" (that do not need extra-memory).

Comment: @PeterRader - Either your understanding of the problem is incorrect, or you have misread my Answer.  When you pass a String object as an argument you are actually passing a 4 or 8 byte reference.  And that reference is being passed on the stack.  Passing an object **of any kind** as an argument does not cause a heap allocation and therefore CANNOT result in an OOME.

Comment: I can reproduct a OOME by using a large string as an parameter. A recursion in my case follows MUCH less loops with a large string! Serioulsy, i do nothing more with the parameter. jdk1.7.0_10.

Comment: The OOME is not caused by **passing** the String.  I challenge you to show me that code.

Comment: Ill be in java-chat :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37102/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-stephen-c)

Comment: @StephenC Sorry I'm using my phone. The question was half baked due to typing difficulty

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of GWT Jetty plugin for Eclipse if you are using GWT Development mode, try to disable dev mode using:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

If it works, you can keep using dev mode if you increase your JVM heap space, for example:

```
-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1224m
```

It has to be a matter of dev. mode because passing a String could hardly cause an OutOfMemory Error.

Comment: Even if the size of the String is ~360KB?

Comment: Try it, however, you should try to find another way to deal with that data because it's too large to keep in memory in terms of performance

Comment: Yes this is exactly my problem, how to deal with a base64 image from clipboard